# addr2line command search path for debug symbols

Tags: c, ubuntu, addr2line

I cannot make *addr2line* to work. It does look for symbols at three (unexisting) paths:

```
/usr/bin/*.debug
/usr/bin/.debug/*.debug
/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/*.debug
```

But it just seems to ignore the path where all debugging symbols are actually installed by default:

```
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/
```

I run *addr2line** like this:

```
addr2line -f -C -e <PathToExecFile> <Addr>
```

Am I missing some configuration switch, system option, or anything similar?

---

That was the question statement, now some proofs for what I'm saying.
Here, I'll be using the program *screen* as an example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install screen screen-dbg
$ file /usr/bin/screen
> /usr/bin/screen: setgid ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
  dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32,
  BuildID[sha1]=e9d3cd5073daa6b7365b3787673143edeec589d3, stripped
$ dpkg -L screen-dbg
> /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/e9/d3cd5073daa6b7365b3787673143edeec589d3.debug
```

Here we empirically found out where the debug symbols for *screen* are:

```
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/e9/d3cd5073daa6b7365b3787673143edeec589d3.debug
```

Now we run *strace addr2line* to see where it tries to access...

```
# Get any valid object address
$ objdump -T /usr/bin/screen
> 00000000006697e0

# Use the object address in addr2line
$ strace -f addr2line -f -C \
    -e /usr/bin/screen 0x00000000006697e0 2>&1 | grep debug
> open("/usr/bin/d3cd5073daa6b7365b3787673143edeec589d3.debug", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
  open("/usr/bin/.debug/d3cd5073daa6b7365b3787673143edeec589d3.debug", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
  open("/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/d3cd5073daa6b7365b3787673143edeec589d3.debug", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Here we see the 3 paths I mentioned earlier, but no signs of the desired one.

Comment: Added bug report in Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/binutils/+bug/1759248